# VS Code Show Where Potential Unhandled Exceptions Could Be Thrown

Tags: php, exception, visual-studio-code, docblocks

In VS Code, doc block info can be automatically generated that looks something like this:

```php
/**
 * Some sample function.
 * @param Request $request 
 * @return JsonResponse 
 * @throws BadRequestException 
 * @throws BindingResolutionException 
 */
public function deleteUploaded(Request $request)
{
  // Some code
}
```

I'm assuming the `@throws` doc info hints at potential exceptions that could be thrown. If so, is there a way to highlight or detect where unhandled exceptions could be thrown in a file in VS Code?

I'd like to be able to more easily find overlooked areas in my code that could potentially throw unhandled exceptions and refactor them.

Comment: There's no native function for it in VSCode afaik. There might be some extension for it, but suggestions/recommendations about tools/libraries/software are unfortunately off-topic here on SO.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some research and see if there are any extensions.